# ASP.NET Core Identity: how to implement 2fa with redirect?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, multi-factor-authentication

ASP.NET Core Identity offers built-in 2fa providers such as SMS, phone and Authenticator app. They all trigger a 2fa flow in the backend (send an SMS, start a phone call, or just ask the user for a code from their auth app). However, we're required to use an external 2fa provider whose process involves redirecting the user to a page on their URL, which will then redirect back to a page on our end which verifies the 2fa token. This is not an OAuth flow.

`IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider` only offers a way to return a string token. I could abuse this by returning a URL and then redirecting in the UI but that seems a misuse of the interface. Still, I'd like to have ASP.NET Identity in charge of deciding which users require 2fa, but that means it also wants to do the 2fa itself.

```
public class ExternalTokenProvider : IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
{
    public async Task<bool> CanGenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, ApplicationUser user)
    {
        return true; //all users require 2fa
    }

    public async Task<string> GenerateAsync(string purpose, UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var challenge = GenerateChallengeToken();
        return $"https://2fa.example.com?user={user.Id}&token={challenge}";
    }

    public async Task<bool> ValidateAsync(string purpose, string token, UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, ApplicationUser user)
    {
        //validate the response token;
    }
}
```

Looking at the implementation of [AuthenticatorTokenProvider](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c5ee07392f0b5bb2ccbfd2ee38d484724ad5bbf3/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/AuthenticatorTokenProvider.cs) I see it simply returns `string.Empty` in `GenerateAsync()`, and then in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI` the `LoginWith2fa.cshtml.cs` page is called. I could do something similar but use the URL retrieved from `GenerateAsync()` to redirect the user.

I've also read [How to register a Two-factor authentication provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity#reg) which still just uses the basic functionality of sending a code via phone/e-mail. It seems the only choice you really have here is to choose the communication gateway.

Is this a proper way to do it within ASP.NET Identity? What's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My implementation ended up not generating the redirect URL in the TokenProvider (because it doesn't seem to be possible to retrieve the generated token/URL from the frontend) but rather copying the [implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c5ee07392f0b5bb2ccbfd2ee38d484724ad5bbf3/src/Identity/UI/src/Areas/Identity/Pages/V5/Account/Login.cshtml.cs#L138) of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI` and just doing it in the frontend:

```
MfaTokenProvider.cs

public async Task<bool> CanGenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(...)
{
    return true;
}

public async Task<string> GenerateAsync(...)
{
    return Task.FromResult(string.Empty);
}

public async Task<bool> ValidateAsync(...)
{
    return _mfaProvider.ValidateToken(token, user.Email);
}
```

```
AccountController.cs

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginForm form)
{
    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(form.Username, form.Password, form.RememberMe, false);

    if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
    {
        var authenticationUrl = _mfaProvider.GetUrl(form.Username, form.ReturnUrl);
        return RedirectResult(authenticationUrl);
    }
    return RedirectResult(form.ReturnUrl);
}
```

This has the advantage of leaving `RequiresTwoFactor` managed by Identity. The downside is the implementation of the 2FA is split over 2 classes and can cause issues when needing to offer multiple 2FA options. This is not currently a requirement of my app, however.